# Pandas - Importing multiple worksheets from one excel file with header in one worksheet

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file which has multiple worksheets (no: of worksheets can change). Only the first worksheets has header, the number of columns in all the worksheets are same. I need to import data from all the worksheets into one dataframe.

Should I be using 'for loop' to iterate through each worksheet, how can I combine the dataframe to contain the details of all worksheets? what would be the code? Plz help...

```
import pandas as pd 
sheet_number=len(pd.read_excel('file.xls',sheetname=None) 
print (sheet_number) 
4 
i=0 

for i in sheet_number: 
    df=read_excel('file.xls',sheetname='i') i+=1
```

Comment: what have you tried so far, where is your code & error?

Comment: I am new to coding and this is what I have done... I have managed to get the number of worksheets in the excel file. I am stuck at the for loop, don't know how to write the code to iterate through each sheet and combine the data into one data  frame....


import pandas as pd
sheet_number=len(pd.read_excel('file.xls',sheetname=None)
print (sheet_number)
4

i=0
for i in sheet_number:
df=read_excel('file.xls',sheetname='i')
i+=1

This is what I have written, the for loop is incomplete...

Answer (score 0):

when you use `pd.read_excel` it has an optional argument called `sheet_name` if you set this to None it will read in the entire excel workbook as a dictionary, that is, the key being the sheet name and the value being a dataframe of your excel worksheet.

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_excel(path_to_excel,sheet_name=None,header=None)

#next we need to grab the headers from the first worksheet.
sheet1 = next(iter(dfs))
cols = dfs[sheet1].iloc[0].values #next(inter) grabs the first key.

#remove row with header in first sheet.
dfs[sheet1] = dfs[sheet1].iloc[1:]

#finally concat dataframe.
df = pd.concat(dfs)
df.columns = cols

       A   B   C
Sheet1 1   0   1   2
       2   3   4   5
       3   6   7   8
       4   9  10  11
       5  12  13  14
Sheet2 0   0   1   2
       1   3   4   5
       2   6   7   8
       3   9  10  11
       4  12  13  14
Sheet3 0   0   1   2
       1   3   4   5
       2   6   7   8
       3   9  10  11
       4  12  13  14
```

Comment: The code worked. ..... the imported data frame has many columns and rows with blank data. Which I would like to delete. If I first delete all the rows and create a new df and then delete all columns df1. Is there an easier method..? This is code I was thinking of using..... df=df0.dropna(how=‘all’,axis=1) and then use df1=df.drop.na(how=‘all’,axis=0)

Comment: @ssks not following - why dont you update your question?